# Changing part of a website with a single button click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am currently experimenting with some code. My mission is to have part of the website change as i click a button.

This is the HTML code;

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="webside">
 
<div class="header">
<p class="headerfont">ElevValgomat</p>
</div>

<div class="upperBody">
<div class="question">

<p id="sporsmaal">Dette er et spørsmål.</p>


<div class="uenig"></div>
<div class="littUenig"></div>
<div class="vetIkke"></div>
<div class="littenig"></div>
<div class="enig"></div>

<p id="forklaring">Uenig</p>
<p id="forklaring">Vet ikke</p>
<p id="forklaring">Enig</p>

<button onClick="question()">Neste</button>
 
</div>
</div>

<div class="lowerBody">
<div class="faktaboks">
 

<div class="eo"></div>
<p id="temaHeaderRegular">Mer om</p><p id="temaHeaderBold">&nbsp;temaet</p>
<p id="tema"> Dette er en faktasetning om temaet vi skal ha spørsmål om. trykk her for å asdfg hei jeg heter sondre osv osv osv osv hei hei hei.</p>


</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Javascript which is in a different document.

```
function question() {
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function()) {
    $("#question2").click(function()) {
        $("#question").load("question2.html");
    }
}
```

}

So these are linked and my intention is to make the javascript run another html document which will fill my container.

Answer (score 1):

Your b uttons doesn't have the id "question2", so your onclick event is never triggered

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="webside">
 
<div class="header">
<p class="headerfont">ElevValgomat</p>
</div>

<div class="upperBody">
<div class="question">

<p id="sporsmaal">Dette er et spørsmål.</p>


<div class="uenig"></div>
<div class="littUenig"></div>
<div class="vetIkke"></div>
<div class="littenig"></div>
<div class="enig"></div>

<p id="forklaring">Uenig</p>
<p id="forklaring">Vet ikke</p>
<p id="forklaring">Enig</p>

<button id="question2">Neste</button>
 
</div>
</div>

<div class="lowerBody">
<div class="faktaboks">
 

<div class="eo"></div>
<p id="temaHeaderRegular">Mer om</p><p id="temaHeaderBold">&nbsp;temaet</p>
<p id="tema"> Dette er en faktasetning om temaet vi skal ha spørsmål om. trykk her for å asdfg hei jeg heter sondre osv osv osv osv hei hei hei.</p>


</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
"use strict";
    $(document).ready(function()) {
        $("#question2").click(function()) {
            $("#question").load("question2.html");
        }
    }
```